# Is there any way to use JSX or similar with Backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, reactjs

One of the things I like about React is putting the template and view code in the same file (without string concatenation). Is there a way to do something similar in Backbone? So:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>blah blah</div>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

With Babel you can specify a @jsx pragma pointing to any function with the signature `function(type, props, ...children){}`.

Here's a minimal self contained example (don't use this in production, it doesn't escape children).

```
// jsx.js
// don't ask why it's all weird looking...
function stringJsxThingy(function(tag,props){return"<"+tag+"\x20"+Object['keys'](props||{})['map'](function(key){return(key+'="'+props[key]['replace'](/"/,'&quot;')+'"')})['join']('\x20')+'>'+[]['slice']['call'](arguments,2)['join']('')+'</'+tag+'>';});
```

And assuming you include that on your page, and include the following:

```
// MyView.js

/** @jsx stringJsxThingy */
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render() {
    this.$el.html(
      <div class="hello">hey</div>
    );
  }
});
```

Which when run through babel gives:

```
/** @jsx stringJsxThingy */
"use strict";

var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function render() {
    this.$el.html(stringJsxThingy(
      "div",
      { "class": "hello" },
      "hey"
    ));
  }
});
```

There are some real libraries out there, but I don't know which interop with jsx well.

---

That was the direct answer, but why not just use React *with* backbone? The view system in backbone is so minimal that no serious applications <sup>[citation needed]</sup> use it alone.

Answer (score 3):

React's JSX transpiler used to require the use of a pragma comment to specify on object containing tag-named functions to transpile JSX tags to function calls. This made it possible to provide your own backend and use it instead of `React.DOM` - one of the core developers made a DOM backend as a an example: [JSXDOM](https://github.com/vjeux/jsxdom).

Things have changed a bit since then - the pragma comment is no longer required and React's JSX transpiler assumes you're using React and transpiles to `React.createElement()` calls. Given that, another option is to simply copy React's JSX transpiling code and tweak it to output something else - for an example of doing this, I did this with [MSX](https://github.com/insin/msx), which allows you to use JSX with [Mithril](http://lhorie.github.io/mithril/).

---

[Babel](http://babeljs.io/) also has an implementation of a JSX transpiler for React. Babel supports plugins, too. It would be ideal if you could use JSX anywhere and tell Babel what you want it to transpile to with a plugin, but last time I looked, I couldn't see an easy way to reuse the guts of Babel's JSX transpiler and just tweak the output.

---

You could also keep the template in the view by using a regular DOM building library in your `render()` method. [creationix/dombuilder](https://github.com/creationix/dombuilder) used to be a favourite of mine when I was working with Backbone, but there are dozens of DOM building libraries in JSON-ML and function call flavours.

Comment: It's worth noting that JSXDOM hasn't been touched in a year and 10 months.

Answer (score 2):

The thing about JSX is that it is transpiled to a tree structure so it can be used to create DOM or virtual DOM. If you are using string-based templating you don't really need that. For example, you can use ES6 string template literals:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render() {
    const name = this.model.get('name');
    this.$el.html(`
      <div class="hello">hello, ${name}!</div>
    `);
  }
});
```